# Cubic equation - Double root

Tags: cubics

I've been having trouble with this problem:

For which values of $k$ does the equation have a double root?
$$x^3-kx^2+k-1=0$$

The correct answer is: $k=-3$, $\frac{3}{2}$, $1$

Thanks!!!

Comment: **Hint:** It factors as $-(x-1) \left(k x+k-x^2-x-1\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to point out that your question is insufficiently imprecise. It should ask for the **real** values of $k$ for which the **real** polynomial given has **real/complex** double roots.

An alternative method is to factorize the cubic, but note that this does not work when you cannot factorize, whereas the other method by *Arnaldo* works in all cases.

$x^3 - k x^2 + k x - 1 = (x-1) ( x^2 + x + 1 ) - k (x-1) (x+1) = (x-1) ( x^2 - (k-1) x - (k-1) )$.

For this cubic to have a double root, either the double root must be $1$, or the quadratic factor must have the double root. In the first case $(x-1)$ must be a factor of $( x^2 - (k-1) x - (k-1) )$, or equivalently $1^2 - (k-1) (1) - (k-1) = 0$. In the second case $( x^2 - (k-1) x - (k-1) )$ must be divisible by $(x-c)^2$ for some real $c$, and since they are both quadratics with leading coefficient $1$, it must be that $x^2 - (k-1) x - (k-1)$ and $(x-c)^2$ are the same polynomials, so we must have $k = 2c+1$ and $c^2 + 2c = 0$.

The above shows what $k$ must be for the cubic to have a double root. You still need to check that the possibilities found actually work.

Comment: Yes, looking at it now my question was quite imprecise. This was an exercise that was part of a practice test, so i just freely translated it to English. Thanks a lot for the very detailed answer! :)

Comment: @bananab0b: You're welcome! You can click the tick to mark an answer as accepted, though you can't accept both, but after you get enough reputation you would be able to upvote helpful answers if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If $a$ is a double root then:

$$f(a)=a^3-ka^2+k-1=0$$

$$f'(a)=3a^2-2ka=0=a(3a-2k) \rightarrow a=0 \quad \text{or} \quad a=\frac{2k}{3}$$

*Ps.: By the rational root theorem, $1$ is a root of $f(x)$: If $1$ is the double root who is $k$? If not, where is the double root?*

Can you finish?

Comment: Thanks so much for answering, I'm thinking really hard atm :D

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: I think i can actually finish now, thanks again!!! You are a real mvp :)